# Error después de la migración de wordpress - No se puede crear nuevas páginas

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

Buen día,

acabo de migrar mi Wordpress pero al hacerlo me dejo de funcinar la creación de nuevas páginas y entradas, le doy al botón de crear y me tira a una página de error 500

Me podrían indicar como puede solucinarlo,

Gracias de Antemano

Comment: migrar de donde hacia donde? como es la migración?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Lo movi de un server a otro y le instale un certificado de seguridad

Comment: Pero ¿cómo lo moviste, a mano, con algún plugin de migración, etc? ¿La base de datos se llama igual en los sitios? ¿Cuando entraste por primera vez al nuevo sitio no te dijo nada? ...

Comment: como fue la movida: ftp, ssh, wget, wp-cli? fijate permisos de carpetas, cambió el dominio? cambiaste de http a https?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Lo movi por ssh y si tienen los mismos permisos estoy trabajando con ubuntu 18.04 y desde base de datos lo cambio de http a https

Comment: @A.Cedano lo movi por ssh y a entarar no me dio ningun problema hasta que empece a agregar contenido y quise añadir una página y me da error 500 al presionar el boton de crear

Comment: ¿Cuando hablas del botón de crear te refieres a que intentas publicar una entrada y no te deja? ¿Puedes activar el modo debug y decirnos qué error te tira?

Comment: fijate si el .htaccess tiene bien el `rewritebase` en caso de estar debería apuntar a la carpeta root del nuevo server

Comment: @A.Cedano Me da estos errores 
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Function create_function() is deprecated in <b>/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-content-editor-lite/includes/ce/shortcode/ShortcodeBase.php</b> on line <b>109</b><br>
<br>
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Function create_function() is deprecated in <b>/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php</b> on line <b>499</b><br>

Comment: Eso es problema de algún plugin, por la URL se llama algo así como *motopress* y/o *revslider*, actualiza ese plugin o bien desactívalo temporalmente. De paso, has de saber que todos los plugin deben estar al día.

Comment: Si te muestra __deprecated__ es porque estás utilizando funciones obsoletas. Al cambiar tu código de un server a otro seguramente la versión de PHP es más reciente por eso el __deprecated__

Comment: @Piropeator Gracias hombre creo que probare con eso mil gracias

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias estaré probando esas opciones para resolver mi problema

Comment: La versión de PHP del nuevo server es más moderna.
Yo 1) desactivaría todos los plugins 2)chequearía el theme no sea que esté obsoleto y haya que actualizarlo. 3) actualizaría los plugins 4)activaria los plugins 1 a 1 por si alguno da error

Comment: Activa el modo debug para que te de el error exacto, porque Error 500 es muy generico https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/como-activar-modo-debug-wordpress/